# How To Override Constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overriding

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class WrappedWriter extends PrintWriter {
  public WrappedWriter(OutputStream o){
    super(o);
  }

  public WrappedWriter(File f) throws FileNotFoundException{
    super(f);
  }

  public WrappedWriter(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{
    super(s);
  }
}
```

As you can see, PrintWriter is being extended by this class.  In the WrappedWriter class, I go on to create a string which I can print either to the terminal or write to a file.  I am told that in order to write it to a file, I have to insert something into the second and third constructor here.  I have already put super() in order to call upon the parent class, but I am trying to find out how I can write the String I end up getting to the File f by typing code in the constructor.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is what is supposed to happen when I put in certain inputs in the interactive mode.

```
 WrappedWriter out = new WrappedWriter(System.out)
 out = new WrappedWriter("gettysburg.txt");
 out.println("Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.")
 out.close();
```

After out.close is typed in, it is supposed to write the string to the file gettysburg.txt, however it is not doing so.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking.  If `f` is a file and you construct a `WrappedWriter` with `new WrappedWriter(f)`, you don't  have a `String` yet.  So whatever it is you want to do, it probably doesn't involve adding anything to the constructors.

Comment: Your question is extremly unclear, but you should probably not extend PrintWriter. You should use a PrintWriter instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I am told that in order to write to a file, I have to insert something into the second and third constructor[s]

You have been misinformed. Both those constructors will cause the writer to write to a file. See the Javadoc for PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really "override" a constructor, as doing so would open the possibility of allowing some of the "super class instances" to skip initialization.

You can "chain" a constructor, by writing a sub-class constructor with the same parameter list.  If you do that, the compiler will add (if you forget to add it explicitly) a `super(...)` call which matches the parameters as the first line of the sub-class constructor block.

As for your question about the `close()` method...  Well, that's not a constructor, and you can override the close method, even to the point that it doesn't close the file.  It wouldn't be recommended, as it would violate the Liskov substitution principle, which would create lots of issues, but it *could* be done.

Comment: *Liskov* substitution principle?